Load master-detail-table with TDataSetProvider and TClientDataSet
I work with an Advantage database in my application (Delphi 12). The database has a master-detail relationship. I provide a simple XML export function for the database. This is implemented as follows: ("Table" is the master-table to export...)
Table.First;
DataSetProvider := TDataSetProvider.Create(nil);
try
  DataSetProvider.Dataset := Table;
  ClientDataSet := TClientDataSet.Create(nil);
  try
    ClientDataSet.SetProvider(DataSetProvider);
    ClientDataSet.Open;
    ClientDataSet.SaveToFile(XMLSaveDialog.Filename, dfXMLUTF8);
    ClientDataSet.Close;
  finally
    ClientDataSet.Free;
  end
finally
  DataSetProvider.Free;
end;

This works well and the data from the detail table is automatically included in the exported XML!
I am now also providing an import function in which the data is to be read from the same XML. Is there a way to import the detail table just as easily and automatically using TDataSetProvider and TClientDataSet without parsing each data record individually for the detail data? Just reading the XML the same way only reads the master-table. Is there a way to tell TDataSetProvider and TClientDataSet what the detail-table is and read that also? Thanks for any hints...

The master-detail relationship is not visible in your question. If structures are identical LoadFromFile works identical, nested set is loaded. If you need run-time setup see Uwe's answer to my question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78871232/nested-datasets-tclientdataset-datasetfield-empty-after-createdataset-nested-s

The details of the master-detail-relationship are not important here, so I did not show them. Your comment was very useful and led me to the correct answer from Uwe. Somehow i did completely miss the concept of nested tables until now. Therefor I learnd a lot, thanks!
